# Place concatenated js directly into html script tag using grunt?

Tags: deployment, gruntjs

Right now my grunt build places all of the concatenated js and css into a scripts.xxx.js, vendor.xxx.js, main.xxx.cs and vendor.xxx.cs. Is there a way to have grunt not put the code into these files, but rather put them directly into the html?

So I would end up with:

```
<html>
    ....

    <style>
        // all of the stuff in main.xxx.cs and vendor.xxx.cs
    </style>

    ....

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // all of the stuff in scripts.xxx.js and vendor.xxx.js
    </script>

    ....
</html>
```

I'm writing a custom module for an existing tool and it would make it a lot easier to just deploy a single html file with everything embedded right in it. Can it be done with grunt or something else? Any thoughts on this approach?

Comment: You should be able to do it with grunt using template strings, as far as compiling all the data to load into those strings - not sure

Comment: @theaccordance thanks -- i'll look into template strings. I should note that I'm new to grunt so any other 'keywords' to look at would likely help me.